# Skulpt vs Trinket.io Python Version

Tags: python, python-3.x, embed, skulpt

I'm confused. On http://skulpt.org/ it says, under "what's new?":

> Python 3 Grammar. The master branch is now building and running using the grammar for Python 3.7.3. There are still lots of things to implement under the hood, but we have made a huge leap forward in Python 3 compatibility. We will still support Python 2 as an option going forward for projects that rely on it.

It also says on the site that the way to embed Skulpt on a site is using Trinket.io. However, on Trinket.io, if you create a new Trinket, the only free option is "Python". It doesn't specify the version, but there is a locked option for "Python 3."

What is the deal please? Is it that Trinket.io offers a paid version of Skulp that supports Python 3? Or are the default "Python" trinkets "kinda sorta" Python 3, as described on the Skulpt homepage? Or what?

The bottom line is, I want to embed some Python 3 on my site, but I'm not ready to pay for a subscription. Is this possible please?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Trinket.io doesn't use Skulpt for Python 3 anymore. When you run a Python 3 code on Trinket.io it says "Connecting to server" which wouldn't be necessary with Skulpt.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).